# Microsoft Azure, loading data freezes W10 app

Tags: c#, azure, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to load some data from Azure. I created a Data Access Layer. My ViewModel goes through the model which goes through the DAL in order to load the data.

When I put the same code in my ViewModel, it works. When I try running it from the DAL, the app freezes and I receive no errors.

Here's the code:

```
// ViewModel.

        public async Task<List<ClassData>> Test()

    {

        try

        {

            var y = await App.MobileService.GetTable<ClassData>().ToListAsync();

        }

....







// Data Access Layer

        public static async Task<List<ClassData>> GetClassList()

    {

        try

        {

            var y = await App.MobileService.GetTable<ClassData>().ToListAsync();

            return null;

        }

....
```

So, in the DAL, var y = await ....  just causes the app to hang and never completes the operation or anything after it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are using new Mobile Apps (from new portal) or old Mobile Services (from old portal)?

Comment: New. The problem was: I was going from the ViewModel to the Model to my DataAccessLayer, but one of those layers wasn't using await (I forget exactly, since I scrapped the DAL after I figured out the problem and decided to do it a different way.)

Answer (score 0):

The first idea is to try replace ToListAsync() with ToCollectionAsync()

What references are you using and what version?
Are you using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client (as you should use) or you using WindowsAzure.MobileService?

Comment: New. The problem was: I was going from the ViewModel to the Model to my DataAccessLayer, but one of those layers wasn't using await (I forget exactly, since I scrapped the DAL after I figured out the problem and decided to do it a different way.)